# Finding out number of bytes read/written in Windows for the day?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, storage

Is there a way to determine how many bytes were read or written in Windows (by *all* programs, including Windows itself) in, say an hour or 24 hours? For example, I need to know the bytes written (sequential and random writes) and bytes read(sequential and random reads).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This little program keeps track of that, once installed and running it keeps those stats on the summary page of the program.

http://www.hddled.com/download/

free, but you will get small nag message if you don't buy, but it will continue to work, buy it if you like it.

Comment: HDDled.exe version 1.104 is not a valid Win32 application according to Windows Home Server SP2.

Comment: Try the support page http://www.hddled.com/support/